# how to use cast on data frame with 3 columns

Tags: r, reshape

In the following data.frame

```
Date1 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 02:00"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 06:00"), by = 3600)
Dat <- data.frame(DateTime = Date1,
                  Temp = rnorm(length(Date1)),
                  height = c(1,2,3,4,5))
Dat2 <- data.frame(DateTime = Date1,
                   Temp = rnorm(length(Date1)),
                   height = c(1,2,3,4,5))

Dat3 <- rbind(Dat,Dat2)
```

I would like to be able to use cast to re-structure the data.frame so that I end up with Time in the first column and then temp in the remaining column, where the values in height are used to define which column each of the values go into. I have seen cast in reshape being used a lot but if I try

```
require(reshape)
cast(Dat3,Temp ~ height)
```

I receive an error

```
Using height as value column.  Use the value argument to cast to override this choice
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , variables, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Eh... The error message is pretty straightforward. Your dataset contains the variables "DateTime", "x1", and "height", but you're referring to some non-existent variable named "Temp".

Comment: I just copied that in wrong, see edited example

Comment: Could you clarify the desired output and provide an example?

Comment: I can't really provide an example of the output, otherwise I wouldn't be asking the question :) the solution should be similar to what Ananta has shown below but I thought it could be done with cast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited:

you can try with `reshape2`

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(Dat3,DateTime ~ height)
```

I also edited your example data to make it clear, (as I understood)

```
Date1 <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 02:00"), 
             to = as.POSIXct("2010-05-01 06:00"), by = 3600)

dat3<-data.frame(DateTime=Date1, Temp=rnorm(25),height=rep(c(1:5), each=5))
```

data:

```
> dat3
              DateTime       temp height
1  2010-05-01 02:00:00 -0.1528124      1
2  2010-05-01 03:00:00 -0.1212748      1
3  2010-05-01 04:00:00 -0.3402005      1
4  2010-05-01 05:00:00 -0.4789695      1
5  2010-05-01 06:00:00  1.0711143      1
6  2010-05-01 02:00:00  0.5340149      2
7  2010-05-01 03:00:00 -0.6660925      2
8  2010-05-01 04:00:00  2.6568830      2
9  2010-05-01 05:00:00 -0.1686520      2
10 2010-05-01 06:00:00  0.5323944      2
11 2010-05-01 02:00:00  1.0419971      3
12 2010-05-01 03:00:00 -1.2008618      3
13 2010-05-01 04:00:00  1.3663645      3
14 2010-05-01 05:00:00 -0.7694349      3
15 2010-05-01 06:00:00  0.6992724      3
16 2010-05-01 02:00:00  1.3105646      4
17 2010-05-01 03:00:00 -0.9245039      4
18 2010-05-01 04:00:00 -1.8716493      4
19 2010-05-01 05:00:00 -1.2540669      4
20 2010-05-01 06:00:00  0.2525718      4
21 2010-05-01 02:00:00 -1.1807661      5
22 2010-05-01 03:00:00 -0.8894825      5
23 2010-05-01 04:00:00 -1.7290931      5
24 2010-05-01 05:00:00 -0.5112744      5
25 2010-05-01 06:00:00 -0.1841737      5
```

code to reshape

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(dat3,DateTime ~ height, value.var="Temp")
```

reshaped data

```
> dcast(dat3,DateTime ~ height, value.var="Temp")
             DateTime          1          2          3          4          5
1 2010-05-01 02:00:00 -0.1528124  0.5340149  1.0419971  1.3105646 -1.1807661
2 2010-05-01 03:00:00 -0.1212748 -0.6660925 -1.2008618 -0.9245039 -0.8894825
3 2010-05-01 04:00:00 -0.3402005  2.6568830  1.3663645 -1.8716493 -1.7290931
4 2010-05-01 05:00:00 -0.4789695 -0.1686520 -0.7694349 -1.2540669 -0.5112744
5 2010-05-01 06:00:00  1.0711143  0.5323944  0.6992724  0.2525718 -0.1841737
```

Comment: Can this not be done with cast? I receive a warning message Using height as value column: use value.var to override.
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length,

Comment: well may be it can be done, but reshape2 is improved version, yes you are right you have to use value.var="Temp" and seems your data has 2 values for same date time and height, so it will default to length

Answer (score 4):

Two points:

1. You're using an old version of a package that has been replaced by the "reshape2" package.
2. When in doubt, try explicitly naming some of your function arguments to help see how the function is working.

For the first point, see the other answer.

For the second point, you can try something like:

```
cast(Dat3, DateTime ~ height, value = "Temp", fun.aggregate = mean)
```

(For a comparable "reshape2" version of the above, you would use `dcast(Dat3, DateTime ~ height, value.var="Temp", fun.aggregate=mean)`)

Let's break this down (also applies to the other answer).

- Tell `cast` (or preferably `dcast`) what data you are using.
- Specify a `formula` describing what you want as your "fixed" columns (like ID variables) to the left of the `~`, and the things that should become column names for the aggregated values.
- Specify a `value` variable (or a `value.var` in `dcast`) as the variable that you want to perform the aggregation on.
- Specify your aggregation function (which, by default, is length, and in my example, is `mean`).

---

I *think* that this is happening in `cast` because of how the `formula` is parsed and how the different variables are guessed. In "reshape", if I remember correctly, if you dig through the code, if a `value` argument is not specified, the function:

- Tries to find a variable named "value", and if that is found, uses that as the `value` argument.
- If that is not found, it uses whatever column is the last (right-most) column in the `data.frame` as the `value` column.
- If that last column happens to already be named in the `formula`--as it is in your example--that column is not available to the function to be used as a value for the `value` argument, so you get this error.

Regarding that last point, "reshape2" does not have this problem, you *can* re-use variables for multiple arguments.

To review the code yourself, type `cast` and `reshape1` at the prompt with the "reshape" package loaded, and `dcast` and `reshape2:::cast` at the prompt with the "reshape2" package loaded. You might have to dig a bit further, because both of these make use of some other functions that Hadley wrote as part of the packages.